# How to show the content of an earlier commit [Gitlab]?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gitlab

How can I show the content of an earlier version of a file in Gitlab? I.e. I want in the same view the current version and the version the user picks to see. Thnx

Comment: Select you GitLab project, clic on `Files` on the top menu, select the file you want to see. In the right top you have some buttons, maybe `Blame` and `History` can help you.

Comment: Found it: **@product.project.repo.commits[n].tree.contents[m].data** where n is the number of the commit, and m is the number of the file in the repository (in my case always 0 since I fetch data from a file I create on project creation).